# Chain `top` output redirection and other commands

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to record system metrics using `top` while other processes are running. I'm hoping to chain things together, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Redirect `top` output
top -U $USER > file.txt &&
# Then run a process that just sleeps for 4 seconds
python3 -c 'import time;time.sleep(4)' &&
# Then run another process that does the same
python3 -c 'import time;time.sleep(4)'
```

When I run this, however, the latter two (Python) processes never complete. My goal is to start recording from `top` before any of the other processes start, then once those processes complete, stop recording from `top`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#run the first command in background
top -U $USER > file.txt &
# Then run a process that just sleeps for 4 seconds
python3 -c 'import time;time.sleep(4)' &&
# Then run another process that does the same
python3 -c 'import time;time.sleep(4)' &&
# kill the command in background
kill %1
```

Comment: I get a syntax error: `./runner.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
./runner.sh: line 4: `top -U $USER > file.txt & &&'`